# Self-transfer with 2h layover in Riyadh: Can I checkin luggage?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, saudi-arabia, self-transfer

I am an Indian passport holder with US permanent resident card.

I am flying Saudia from Casablanca to Riyadh and then 2h later, Air India from Riyadh to Mumbai. The flights are on two different PNRs and were booked on kiwi.com which says that it’s a “self-transfer”

I confirmed that I’m ineligible for the transit VISA - the Saudi transit VISA website explicitly states that and the consulate agent in Rabat, Morocco also confirmed that.

Given that I’m ineligible for transit VISA, it means I cannot recheckin my bag at Riyadh. Is that right?

My bag is a big backpack - that is just slightly above cabin baggage limits but I’ve typically not had a problem taking it in the cabin.

I also understand that it may be feasible to ask Saudia to transfer my luggage to Air India depending upon whether they have an interlining agreement. Do they have one? Is it risky to opt for transfer - in other words, is it common for bags to be lost when such a transfer is requested?

Comment: You are eligible for visa on arrival, being a permanenet resident of the US. It is just the connection time which would be a problem.

Comment: In your shoes I would be more worried about being refused boarding on your first flight because you don't have a Saudi visa or a connecting flight on the same ticket.

Comment: Gotcha, I can’t seem to confirm VISA on arrival for US Green Card but if that’s the case, then @lambshaanxy, I shouldn’t be refused boarding, correct?

Comment: @ThomasCruise - is that because, the steps would involve immigration twice? are there ways to expedite moving through that? The Saudi consulate agent I was able to speak to said that I can just stay airside, if I don’t checkin any baggage… but I don’t know how the terminals are connected in Riyadh 

Comment: @ Vighnesh I am not sure about the terminals. You should be able to find that out with a little search on the internet. Find out the terminals and look for the airport map at the website. There may even be some experiences posted, even videos. The visa on arrival info is mentioned on both these websites:

https://www.visitsaudi.com/en/travel-regulations

                  https://www.saudia.com/pages/before-flying/travel-information/hajj-and-umrah/tourist-visa

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend against trying this. In almost all cases the first airline (Saudia) will need to verify that you can legally enter Saudia Arabia or they can't let you board. The fact that you have a second ticket to India is immaterial to them.

In very rare cases, you may be able talk the check-in agent into letting you board with an onward ticket that departs from the same transit area where you arrive, but in 95%+ of all cases you will simply be denied boarding.

Two hours is also extremely tight. Personally I don't do self transfer under 4 hours (even with full visa, etc.) simply because the consequences of missing the connection are dire: typically you end up having to buy a new same-day ticket out of pocket which tends to be VERY expensive. Two hours with checked bags seems extremely risky.

Please read carefully what KIWI has to say on the topic:
https://www.kiwi.com/en/help/kiwi-com-travel-hacks-258/article/self-transfer-travel-hack-131/